# Creating installer for Qt + OpenGL + GLUT + GLEW app

Tags: qt, opengl, installation, glut, glew

We (my classmates and I in college) have created a 3D medical visualization software using the programs / libraries listed in the title. Now we would love to create an installer for our app, but we don't seem to find the right solution. I've been looking around, and seen some cool programs that compile everything you got and create the installer, but my question is as follows:

Does it compile, link, and add to the installer GLUT and GLEW libraries?

We've had a hard time installing all of that crap on windows, i just can't picture a doctor going through the same painfull process, if you know what I mean...

So, is there any application that can make this possible?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bits. Qt Creator 2.4. GLEW and GLUT lastest libraries, and the app is in C++

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [voreen](http://www.voreen.org/) which is open source and also use Qt, GLEW and GLUT to implement a volume render engine software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off: OpenGL is not a library, it's an API. And the only way to get proper support for it in Windows is to install the original graphics drivers, downloaded from the GPU vendor's homepage. So as part of the installer you should detect the installed GPU and check for the installed drivers, possibly redirecting the user to the driver download page of the GPU vendor.

Installers are pretty much standard stuff. The most easy, and reliable way to go, is to place copies of all the DLL files of the used libraries in the same directory as the program executable. Have a look at the [NullSoft Installer System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/)

You say you use Qt together with GLUT? Why? Qt and GLUT don't play together. The only reason to use GLUT I see is the teapot.

GLEW is a pretty standard DLL, but I usually tent to statically link it with my renderer module.

Comment: Ty for your response! Well, you're obviously right, we're NOT using GLUT, that was the previous approach, sry. Yes, i know OpenGL is an API, and yes, I know that client must install latest drivers. But I'm more concerned about GLEW. So, as you say, I should simply put glew32.dll inside my app's folder and then link the library there? Well, no one explained it that easy.... please, let me know if I'm OK or wrong. Thanks

Comment: oh, and i forgot... you say (and quote) "So as part of the installer you should detect the installed GPU and check for the installed drivers". Since I'm totally n00b here, would you please point me in any direction? Does NullSoft Installer (checking it now...) have that feature?

Comment: dude, I'm sorry again, but we do use GLUT, and we do so not for the windows API but for the type definitions, such as GLfloat, GLint and so on.

Comment: @TIMINeutron: Those type definitions are not in GLUT, they are in the regular OpenGL headers. Checking for GPU availability is done by writing a small program/library, that performs the necessary checks and bundling it into the installer. GLEW you can either link dynamically (then you need the DLL) or statically, where no further DLL is required. I usually tend to link my render code statically together with GLEW; but that's my way of doing it, which is neither best or worst, but just my choice.

Comment: you're right, and i was wrong again. We must import GLUT because we use another library, called GLM by Nate Robin ([link](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/tutors.html)), and it has serious dependences with GLUT (it's a library to parse *.obj 3D objects). Then, obviously, we have to compile it all together.

Comment: @TIMINeutron: GLM definitely has no dependencies on GLUT. It may use GLUT for it's example code, but GLM itself is framework agnostic.

Comment: sorry couldn't answer before, was too bussy in college. OK, if it's that way, how is it that the source code of the library imports GLUT? And, if not necessary, which other include should I do to get it working? Becouse, obviously, if I delete it I get A LOT of compiler and errors

Comment: @TIMINeutron: All of the examples make use of GLUT, but the GLM library itself just includes GLUT, although ordinary GL/gl.h would suffice. So I suggest you just replace GLUT/glut.h and GL/glut.h with just GL/gl.h and be gone with it. (As long as you don't use the example code you're fine).

Comment: I think we don't... But that wasn't my part of the project, so I should ask the other guys wether we use it or not. Anyway, I think that would be all. Thanks so much for everything. I think we will try to make the installer, but looking at the whole picture, maybe we deliver a plain *.zip for now (it's only a college project, not THAT important) :)